# Using List<Classname> in Macros in Kentico E-mail Template

Tags: c#, macros, kentico, email-templates

I have a list of class object called Notifications

```
 public class Notifications
    { 
        public string Name { get; set; }  
    }
```

There is a function that just returns List of Notifications. I want to construct an e-mail template that shows all the Notification information using macros in Kentico, unfortunately when i use the macros methods such as

```
{%

foreach (var Data in Notification) {
 Data.Name
} 

#%}
```

Such macro doesn't return an output at all eventhough i made sure all data was sent successfully to the email , i want to use a foreach loop.

Comment: Are you sure that Notification variable within macro contains data you need? Have you passed that variable to MacroResolver?

Comment: Yes, it is im debugging it and seeing the result before i pass it to the MacroResolver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out,we have to inherit

```
AbstractDataContainer<ClassName>
```

and register the field we're using

```
public class Notifications: AbstractDataContainer<Notifications>
    {   [RegisterColumn]
        public string Name { get; set; }  
    }
```

thus we can use the List in foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

If you are properly registered Notifications list in macro resolver for email template (*SetNamedSourceData*), you should be able to iterate over it with this peace of code (used h1 for testing purposes only):

```
{% foreach (Data in Notification) { %}
 <h1> {% Data.Name %}</h1>
{% } %}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it returned an empty tag

Comment: Did you tried to convert your model to DataSet? It looks like it can't work with custom objects. See this thread for more information: https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/macro-not-resolving-in-email

Comment: i can't convert all what i'm going to send to the email template into a Dataset